# With RSpec, can I specify the documented failures?

Tags: rspec

With RSpec we can use the `--only-failures` flag to run the examples in failed_examples.txt.

If I copy that file over as featured_examples.txt is there a way to run RSpec with examples in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec doesn't seem to support it, but bash to the rescue!

SOmething like this should work

```
cat failed_examples.txt | xargs rspec
```

or maybe

```
rspec $(cat failed_examples.txt)
```

Comment: Ha, thanks! I thought I had done this in a previous project and must have done something like this.